# Create roles in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am trying to create different roles for my website but they aren't saving to the database. I have used this code before on a different project where it worked fine but for some reason it doesn't work on this one.

I have looked at other similar questions on here and tried different ways to get it work working with no luck. It may be something really obvious but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```cs
public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Users.Any())
        {
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
            {
                var roleResults = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
            }

            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Customer"))
            {
                var roleResults = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Customer"));
            }

            var user = userManager.FindByName("admin@admin.com");
            if (user == null)
            {
                var newUser = new Admin()
                {
                    FirstName = "Thomas",
                    LastName = "Green",
                    Email = "admin@admin.com",
                    UserName = "admin@admin.com",
                };

                userManager.Create(newUser, "Admin12345");
                userManager.AddToRole(newUser.Id, "Admin");

            }

            var user2 = userManager.FindByName("customer@test.com");
            if (user2 == null)
            {
                var newUser2 = new Customer()
                {
                    FirstName = "Luke",
                    LastName = "Red",
                    Address = "5 Hilton Court",
                    City = "Glasgow",
                    Postcode = "KA21 6HX",
                    UserName = "customer@test.com",
                    Email = "customer@test.com",

                };
                userManager.Create(newUser2, "Password");
                userManager.AddToRole(newUser2.Id, "Customer");
            }
        }

        base.Seed(context);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing, please edit your question by adding the while method.

Comment: Hey I added all the code that I have but I don't have a while method?

Comment: There's no while method, typo mistake my bad. Your code should work fine, have you checked if the roles and users already exist in the database ?

Comment: I have checked the database but the roles and users I have created there are not in it. I can create a user without adding a role and they get stored in the database so I know there is an issue somewhere but I just can't figure it out.